# Difference between = and new

Tags: java

What is the difference between this:

```
Object one = new Object();
Object two = one;
```

and this:

```
Object one = new Object();
Object two = new Object();
two = one;
```

What would be the effect on object `one` when I change object `two`?

Comment: Try on you own and see what happens.

Comment: Your 2nd snippet currently has a compiler error.

Comment: Your second example wont compile, you can't create `two` reference again. Maybe instead of `object two = one;` you meant `two = one`?

Comment: I have tried, but need some theoretical explanation.

Comment: With `new` keyword you instantiate new object and assign it to variable `one`. `two = one` means that you assign value of variable `one` to variable `two`. I expect that objects should be passed as reference so variable `two` and variable `one` should be holding reference to the same object but I am not sure about internals. I've not touched java for 3 years.

Comment: If you want more theory buy some good book and read java docs.

Comment: @PLB, I do understand your point, I've been working in jave (android) for about a year, its just that at times you hit a low point and forgot some very basic points.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first snippet creates one object, and gives it two "names" (references).

The second snippet creates two objects, but then "forgets" the second one, and replaces it with a reference to the first object:

[image: Diagram]

The last diagram shows the second object with no references. At this point the object becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 5):

Think of objects as boxes, and variables as arrows pointing to those boxes.

So, when you do

```
Object one = new Object();
```

you're creating a new box and a new arrow pointing to the box.

Whereas, when you do

```
Object two = one;
```

you're just creating a new arrow and pointing it to the existing box.

Comment: I wanted this kinda explanations. Thumbs up

Answer (score 2):

The object is on the heap, is shareable to any code which has the reference value, and the `OBJECT` contains the member `variable` values, so it doesn't matter which thread or method changes the data in the `object`. ***It is changed for everyone***.

All `reference` variables are referring to same `Object`.

Lets take a example class **Rectangle**.

[image]

Assigning Object Reference Variables  -

1.*Does not Create Distinct Objects.*
 2.*Does not  Allocate Memory*
 3.*Does not Create duplicate Copy*

[more info :Assigning Object Reference Variables](http://c4learn.com/javaprogramming/assigning-object-reference-variables-class-concept-in-java-programming/)

Answer (score 2):

When you do new,jvm allocates some memory to that object,when you use "=" it gives reference of same memory to the variable on the left side .

Means if you do ,

```
Object x=new Object();
Object x1=x;
```

now both will point to same memory reference and you can access that memory allocation by both of this name ,x and x1.

Comment: Thanks kaushal trivedi. Your answer is correct but `selig` answered it first. Still +1 for you too.

Comment: Thats ok for me,participation in community itself is a great thing.There is no thing like competition here.

Comment: Reason I like your answer was that I understood it, you explained me in very basic way. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

using `new` you are creating a new object, by using `=` you are just assigning a reference to existing object.

Let us first understand what exactly these statements mean.

```
Object one = new Object();
```

Here `Object` is the type `one` is the reference variable and `new Object` actually creates the object and it is referred by `one`.

Now when you are doing `two = one`, the reference variable `two` will also refer to the same object as referred by `one`. i.e. now they both will refer to same object.

Your second snippet is not correct. You cannot create two reference variables of same type and same name. You will have to change it to.

```
   Object two = new Object();
   two = one;
```

Well, this link is a little off topic but it will certainly help you understand how exactly reference variables refer to the objects.
http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/22/how-do-objects-become-eligible-for-garbage-collection/

Answer (score 0):

```
Object one = new Object();
Object two = one;
```

Here you created one object and have two references to this same object.

```
Object one = new Object();
Object two = new Object();
two = one;
```

Here you created two objects but later assigned one of variables with another objects, so you again have two references to the same object, but created extra object which is now to be `garbage collected`.

Answer (score 0):

Effect would be same.

Since both are reference type if you do:

object two = one;

Then both refer to the same memory location and changes in one affect other one.

The only difference between 2 methods is in method 2 you create 2 instances of the 2 different object initially but after `object two = one;` they will be same object.